# H2O - savefig with "performance.plot()" ROC

Tags: python, matplotlib, h2o

When I use H2O 3.19, I want to save the training data's performance `matplotlib.pyplot` graphic (ROC) at server side, how can I do it?

Here we can see the source code of `plot()` in `h2o/model/metrics_base.py`:

```
def plot(self, type="roc", server=False):
    """
    Produce the desired metric plot.

    :param type: the type of metric plot (currently, only ROC supported).
    :param server: if True, generate plot inline using matplotlib's "Agg" backend.
    :returns: None
    """
    # TODO: add more types (i.e. cutoffs)
    assert_is_type(type, "roc")
    # check for matplotlib. exit if absent.
    try:
        imp.find_module('matplotlib')
        import matplotlib
        if server: matplotlib.use('Agg', warn=False)
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    except ImportError:
        print("matplotlib is required for this function!")
        return

    if type == "roc":
        plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate (FPR)')
        plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (TPR)')
        plt.title('ROC Curve')
        plt.text(0.5, 0.5, r'AUC={0:.4f}'.format(self._metric_json["AUC"]))
        plt.plot(self.fprs, self.tprs, 'b--')
        plt.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])
        if not server: plt.show()
```

`plot(type="roc", server=False)` just examines the existence of `matplotlib.pyplot` and does not return the `plt` object, so I cannot call `plt.savefig()`. What can I do?

Comment: What is wrong with importing `pyplot` in your own code?

Comment: I can import, but I cannot get that object with the information (`x.label`, `ylabel`, ect) which I need, if I understand this correctly(unless all info is shared/static?)

Comment: You said "I cannot call `plt.savefig()`", you can after you execute `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Comment: OK I tried, and you are right, I don't have to get the return from inside, the info is shared through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as the comment of @Goyo said, you need to import the `matplotlib.pyplot` where you call `plot()` method, and you can `savefig` there. It seems like that without return it is still possible, so I guess the info is shared between "inside" and "outside", i.e., they are "static" saying in the Java way.

---

<s>At last I have to modify the source code, forcing it to return `plt` when `server is True`, then I call `plot(type="roc", server=True)` from outside. I think it has no impact because before the change, by default it returns `None`.</s>

```
if not server: 
    plt.show()
else:
    return plt # return to use plt.savefig
```